# formatting flattened string into JSON-like object in C++, part 2

Tags: c++, strings, parsing, formatting, c++17

I have reworked the code from my previous (linked) post.

For reference:

I have a string which contains JSON-like object flattened (`stringify()`ed).
I need to JSON-ify it back. It's a custom format, so I wrote function to JSON-ify the string.

Please review it. Also one particular thing that I don't like is `previousIsClosingBracket` variable. I have added it for handling correct formatting of the last example. Is there a better way to detect such cases and have more beautiful solution?

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct WordAtLevel
{
    std::string word;
    std::size_t level;
};

using tWordLevels = std::vector<WordAtLevel>;

class Formatter
{
public:
    explicit Formatter(std::string tclString);
    std::string formatted() const;

private:
    tWordLevels parse() const;
    static std::string build(tWordLevels wordAtLevels);
    std::string readUntilDelimiter() const;
    static bool isClosingBrackets(const std::string &str);
    static std::string indentation(const std::size_t tabCount);

    std::string m_tclString;
    std::size_t m_strLen = 0;
    mutable std::size_t m_idx = 0;
    static constexpr int tabWidth = 4;

    mutable bool m_bPrevWordReserved = false;
    const std::unordered_set<std::string> m_reservedWords{ "coords", "comment" };
};

Formatter::Formatter(std::string tclString)
    : m_tclString(std::move(tclString))
    , m_strLen(m_tclString.length())
{
}

std::string Formatter::formatted() const
{
    const tWordLevels wordLevels = parse();
    return build(wordLevels);
}

tWordLevels Formatter::parse() const
{
    tWordLevels wordAtLevels;
    int level = 0;

    for (m_idx = 0; m_idx < m_strLen; ++m_idx)
    {
        switch (auto ch = m_tclString[m_idx])
        {
            case '}':
            {
                if (m_bPrevWordReserved)
                    m_bPrevWordReserved = false;
                else
                    --level;
                wordAtLevels.emplace_back("}", level);
                break;
            }
            case '{':
                wordAtLevels.emplace_back("{", level);
                if (!m_bPrevWordReserved)
                    ++level;
                [[fallthrough]];
            default:
            {
                std::string word = readUntilDelimiter();
                if (!word.empty())
                {
                    if (m_reservedWords.contains(word))
                        m_bPrevWordReserved = true;

                    wordAtLevels.emplace_back(word, level);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return wordAtLevels;
}

std::string Formatter::build(tWordLevels wordAtLevels)
{
    std::string result;
    const auto wordCount = wordAtLevels.size();
    bool previousIsClosingBracket = false;
    for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx < wordCount; ++idx)
    {
        const auto &[word, level] = wordAtLevels[idx];

        result += indentation(level);
        result += word;

        previousIsClosingBracket = isClosingBrackets(word);
        while (++idx < wordCount)
        {
            const auto &[nextWord, nextLevel] = wordAtLevels[idx];
            if (nextLevel != level)
                break;

            if (previousIsClosingBracket && !isClosingBrackets(nextWord))
                break;
            
            result += ' ';
            result += nextWord;
        }

        result += '\n';
        --idx;
    }
    return result;
}

std::string Formatter::readUntilDelimiter() const
{
    std::string word;
    ++m_idx;
    while (m_idx < m_strLen)
    {
        const auto ch = m_tclString[m_idx];
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '{' || ch == '}')
        {
            --m_idx;
            break;
        }
        ++m_idx;
        word += ch;
    }
    return word;
}

bool Formatter::isClosingBrackets(const std::string& str)
{
    return str == std::string_view("}");
}

std::string Formatter::indentation(const std::size_t tabCount)
{
    return std::string(tabCount * tabWidth, ' ');
}

int main()
{
    const Formatter f1("{data {a {obj {coords {10 10} comment {} radius 260 type circle}}}}");
    std::cout << f1.formatted() << '\n';

    const Formatter f2("{data {b {obj {coords {-95 -85 -70 -85 -75 -95} comment {abc} type polygon}}}}");
    std::cout << f2.formatted() << '\n';

    const Formatter f3("{data {c {obj {coords {-55 -65 -70 -65 -25 -64} comment {abc def} type polygon}}}}");
    std::cout << f3.formatted() << '\n';

    const Formatter f4("{data {d {obj {coords {59 60} comment {} type point}} e {obj {coords {928 324} comment {} type point}}}}");
    std::cout << f4.formatted() << '\n';
}
```